# How to print information from another process?

Tags: c

I have a process `A`, and I use `CreateProcess()` to create process `B`. In `A` I use `ReadProcessMemory()` and `WriteProcessMemory()` to read from/write to `B`.

Now I want to print something in `B` through `A`, should I translate `printf()` into X86 and use `WriteProcessMemory()` to write into `B`, or is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know windows programming, but I saw on MSDN that `WriteProcessMemory()` copies a buffer over to the other process. Given that, you just need to write your data to that buffer and read it on the other side.

If you need formatted read and write, you can use [`sprintf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybk95axf%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (or better, `snprintf`) and [`sscanf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkx076cy.aspx) to write to the buffer and read from it.